# Can I use the "Auto" mode on my Hercules impact wrench to safely put lug nuts on?

Tags: torque, lug-nut, torque-specification, tips-and-tricks, impact-wrench

I'm new to DIY auto mechanic stuff, and I just bought a Hercules 1/2" compact impact wrench (HCB84B2) mainly to get lug nuts off the car. I know you're not supposed to use impact wrenches to put the lug nuts back on, but... The tool advertises having 4 modes, including an "Auto" mode; as described in the manual:

> Set Mode:
>
> Push Speed Selection Button to cycle through 4 modes.
>
> I - 0-1000 RPM and 0-1300 IPM
>
> II - 0-1600 RPM and 0-1900 IPM
>
> III - 0-2000 RPM and 0-2800 IPM
>
> **Auto - Forward: Tool stops within a few impacts when driving small,
> self-tapping metal screws.**
>
> Auto - Reverse: Tool stops once impacting has stopped.

### So my main question is, can I use the Auto (forward) mode to safely get the lug nuts on, and then finish torquing them to proper spec (88 ft. lbs.) with my torque wrench?

I don't quite understand what "stops within a few impacts" means in terms of how torqued the lug nuts will be using that Auto mode. Alternatively, do you think I could safely use the lowest setting to get the lug nuts snug, again finishing with the torque wrench?

I'll take any other tips/advice you might have! I've never taken the wheels off before, and I'm about to do a full brake job. Excited! Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Answer (score 1):

Bottom line is, you can pretty much use your tool the way you want to use it.

The real question is, *should you?* Basically, no you shouldn't. Even in the Auto-Forward mode, it would be way too easy to over torque the lug nuts. This isn't good for the lugs, nuts, or rim. It's a much better practice to just tighten by hand, then torque them while the wheel is on the ground.

Comment: This is the correct answer.  Personally, I use an old plastic faucet tool to spin the lug nuts on by hand while in the air, which is simple and fast.  You could get the same results using a short extension and socket to spin them on by hand then torque on the ground.